# question about polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

for instance, I have 2 model `Drummer` and `Video`

If I use one-to-many association `drummer has_many videos`, and `video belongs_to drummer`,

So I can use the method in both side: `video.drummers` or `drummer.videos`

But when I use polymorphic association, which I think the right to for this, because, there will be a lot model have video, it makes sense make the video model polymorphic

I can use `drummer.videos`,
But I don't know how to get which drummer the video belongs to

`video.drummer` doesn't work,

anybody could tell me how to do this, and what's other methods I can use after I set up the association.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to add a migration file to add columns in videos:

```
class AddPolymorphicReferenceToVideos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :videos, :video_holder_id, :integer
    add_column :videos, :video_holder_type, :string
    add_index :videos, :video_holder_id
    add_index :videos, :video_holder_type
  end

  def self.down
    # just remove indexes and columns above
  end
end
```

Then you can add polymorphic association in `Video` model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :video_holder, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And change your `Drummer` like this:

```
class Drummer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :videos, :as => :video_holder
end
```

Now you can use the polymorphic association:

```
drummer.videos  # => an videos array
video.video_holder  # => a model holds the video
```

Comment: why should I add index of id and type, the app works without the index now, please give me some insight about the index

Comment: Well, the index affects the sql query speed significantly. In one of my app, selecting 100 records out of 6000 without indexes could be 10x slower than having indexes added on columns which are used by `where`, `left|right|inner join`, `order by`, or `group by`. So you can browse your log, find out time-consuming sql queries, and try to add indexes in clauses above, your app would speed up much, or... a little if you have little data in your db :)